# Are there downsides to not explicitly defining database relationships?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a PHP application with a MySQL database. I have not defined any formal relationships between tables. (eg. Set Foreign key, etc).  Although in every query (CRUD) I always consider the relation between tables.

Are there any significant downsides to not defining the relationships formally? Are there any performance issues?

Comment: Constraints do not exist to improve performance.  Constraints exist to insure that any data that you insert or alter in a SQL database *preserves referential integrity.*

Comment: Please don't confuse foreign key constraints with relationships (in the entity-relationship model).  Relationships are recorded IN tables as an association among two or more (usually different) entity sets.  Foreign key constraints enforce a subset restriction between two columns of a single entity set.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a very significant downside. If you make a mistake in the code then you get invalid data in the database. Constraints prevents you from entering invalid data in the database.

Constraints also prevent you from entering invalid data directly through SQL independent of the application.

Of course if you **never ever** make bugs and mistakes, then you don't need constraints.

Comment: unless you make a mistake in your constraints!!!!

Comment: @Ewan: Errors in constraints does not in themselves enter invalid data, you still need the combination of errors in the constraints and errors in the application code.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have appropriate indexes for your queries you should be fine.

You have formally defined the relationships in your sql select statements, which presumably are checked into the code.

I think its fairly common practice to skip foreign key constraints, if you are a dev creating your own DB for use only by one app. It can save you some time worrying about the order of deletes etc.

Although best practice would suggest you add them in at some stage, this will help you catch edge cases and make it easier to maintain going forward.

Comment: "If you are a dev creating your own DB for use only by one app..." I think it's a myth that best practices aren't worth practicing on home projects ... Sooner or later you're going to pick up the project again and either hate your old self or praise your old self. Ok, maybe if you're making something that you're about to nuke and throw away you could skip it... But the "unless I'm the only one who uses it" philosophy seems flawed to me

Comment: Though I suppose you're not saying "I recommend this" but rather "many people do this", and I can't really argue with that

Comment: well the FK constraints are meant to enforce consistency assuming that many users/apps connect to the db. If you only have one app then you can enforce consistency in your datalayer

Comment: but yeah, it only takes a few min to go through and enforce it twice

Comment: "I think its fairly common practice to skip foreign key constraints" <-- While this is true, I have seen a _lot_ of horrible code bases with really bad problems that could have been prevented by applying the proper constraints in the database from the beginning. It is a fairly common practice, but it is a _bad_ practice with real world consequences and costs.

Comment: Surely those problems can be prevented by implementing constraints.. in any layer. My interpretation of the OP is that it is asking about techical downsides rather than design ones